# Найти сумму ряда для определенных элементов

Tags: c++, ряды

Нужно найти сумму ряда для элементов 10,100,1000 и т.д.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
long int i,n;
double Sm,a,b,d;
double s[100000];
for (i = 1; i < 100001; i*=10) {
a=1;
for (n=1; n<i; n++) {
b=72/(5*(n*n+6*n+8));
a=a*b;
s[n]=s[n]+a;
}
printf("s[%d]=%f\n",n,s[n]);
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Но у меня почему-то выводятся везде нули.

Comment: Ну во-первых непонятно, что же надо получить. А во-вторых `b=72/(5*(n*n+6*n+8));` должно давать 0 для любого n>0.

Comment: Нужно получить сумму ряда первых 10,100,1000 и т.д. элементов.
А почему b=72/(5*(n*n+6*n+8)); будет давать 0? 
72/(5*(n*n+6*n+8)) — сам ряд, наверно я его не там объявил.

Comment: Потому что все числа справа от `/` - целые, а 72 - тоже целое. Целое на целое делится по принципу 5/2 = 2; 2/5 = 0. То есть тут всегда будет ноль (72/75, 72/150...). Если исправить 72 на 72.0, то знаменатель приведётся к `double` и будет делиться по-нормальному.

Comment: Потому что 72/(5*(n*n+6*n+8)) -- выражение целое, при n=1 принимает значение 72/75, которое равно 0 (и 72 в остатке). Ответ @GenchiK ситуацию исправляет, выражение приобретает тип double и результат 0.96 (если не ошибся)

Comment: @alexlz всё правильно поняли )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

1.Добавить точку, явно указав что само число дробное, точка ноль после 72(хоть и тип double указан) b=72.0/(5*(n*n+6*n+8));

2.В выводе вместо %f указать %lf.Всё же float, меньше чем double.Может и здесь проблема быть.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)

Comment: Пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще есть специальная методика нахождения суммы ряда. Она заключается в том, что надо **не тупо складывать все числа в цикле**, а перемножать.
Например, чтобы вычислить сумму ряда от 1 до 100 нужно представить этот ряд в виде пар чисел и их суммы. 1 и 100, 2 и 99, 3 и 98 и так далее. Как видно, сумма каждой пары=101(максимальному числу ряда+1), а пар чисел всего 50. Вот и перемножай теперь 101 на 50. Получим 5050. Можешь это проверить в цикле =)

---

**Вот функция, находящая сумму ряда как для четных чисел, так и нет:**

```
int sum_array(const int max)
{
    if(max%2==0)return (max+1)*(max/2);
    if(max%2==1)return (max+1)*(max/2)+(max/2+1);
}
```

Comment: И где вы видите арифметическую или геометрическую прогрессии?

Comment: Это демонстрация метода =)

Comment: Демонстрация метода вычисления суммы арифметической последовательности. Суммы пар чисел равны и вместо сложения их можно умножить на количество пар. Если пары не равны, то что надо умножать и насколько?

Comment: Я предоставил код выше, он работает и для четного, и для нечетного количества пар.

Comment: Где? берем a(n)=72/(5*(n*n+6*n+8)). n=1..10. a(1)+a(10) = 183/175. a(2)+a(9) = 501/715. И что на что надо умножить для получения суммы a(1)+a(2)+..+a(10)?